# GetElementsByTagName format filter (HELP)

Tags: php, html, getelementsbytagname

I'm trying to format a NodeList obtained by getElementsByTagName and I can actually get the content of each tag, but I'm not able to filter, I'm trying to make the output like this:

```
EXAMPLE:

name: jhon doe
number: 12345678
date: 00/00/0000
```

but I only get the normal content:

```
JOHN DOE
12345678
00/00/0000
lane DOE
7234567890
00/30/0000
```

or if I use [0] it returns only the first letter/number of each tag.

```
J
1
0
l
7
3
```

my current code is below, any tips on what i can do?

```
<?php
$string = '
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>JOHN DOE</td>
<td style="background-color: rgb(25, 194, 25);">12345678</td>
<td>00/00/0000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>lANE DOE</td>
<td style="background-color: rgb(25, 194, 25);">7234567890</td>
<td>30/00/0000</td>
</tr>
</tbody>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($string);
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('td') as $td) {
    echo $td->textContent[0] . '<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you expect the `name`,`number` and `date` to come from? PHP doesn't know what the table-values mean, so you have to set them yourself somehow.

There is no indication in the HTML what each table cell means, so you can only guess and hope the table structure never changes. The tables are ordered name - number - date, so you can deduct from the cell number what the label for a particular `<td>` has to be: 0 = name, 1 = number, 2 = date.

So if you parse the HTML per table **row** and after that per table **cell** for each row, you can add a label based on the cell order.

But mind, if the content of the HTML is from an outside source and they change the order of the cells, it goes wrong.

```
//create an array of labels, based on the cell order per row
$labels=[
    0=>'name',
    1=>'number',
    2=>'date'
    ];

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($string);

// search for table ROWS
$table_rows = $dom->getElementsByTagName('tr');

//loop the ROWS
foreach($table_rows as $row){
   //per ROW node, search for table CELLS
   $row_cells = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
   //loop the CELLS
   foreach($row_cells as $number => $cell){
     //echo a label based on the cell order + the contents of the cell
     echo $labels[$number].' - '.$cell->textContent.'<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: THX, it solved my problem and solved a future problem with get 'tr' first. really thanks so much!

Answer (score -2):

The mistake you are doing, is that you are using td tag, which does not return each record, rather it returns each value (look into your code).

**First thing is you should use "tr' tag**

**Second, you should use nodeValue to get data of any specific item by mentioning index**

Given the corrected code for your reference, feel free to ask anything not clear

```
<?php
$string = '
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>JOHN DOE</td>
<td style="background-color: rgb(25, 194, 25);">12345678</td>
<td>00/00/0000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>lANE DOE</td>
<td style="background-color: rgb(25, 194, 25);">7234567890</td>
<td>30/00/0000</td>
</tr>
</tbody>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($string);
$tr = $dom->getElementsByTagName('tr');
echo $tr->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

if you want to output all items, you can simply use loop

Comment: You're right to get the the `<tr>`'s first, but after that per `$tr` you need to get the `<td>`'s and loop those to get the nodevalues.

Comment: Right, in case you want each value separately, BUT in this case, he wants to select the record
And I also mentioned about the loop at the end, if he wants to output or get all items